# Getting runtime cached from cache programatically in case of a 500 error from server

Tags: workbox

I was wondering how one can get content that has been cached via a runtime strategy using workbox programmatically

[image: my workbox config]

From the screenshot above, If I try to log the previousResponse, I get undefined. How can this be accomplished? The reason I'm doing this is that I'm trying to read from the cache when my server returns a 500.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing `fetchDidSucceed` with `cacheDidUpdate`. Further information can be in the documentation for [Workbox: Using Plugins](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/using-plugins).

Comment: Hi, I don't think this will work, The reason I'm doing this is that I'm trying to read from the cache when my server returns a 500.